# How to add checkbox with every image in array and select only one

Tags: angular

```
HTML - 
 <div *ngFor="let image of result; let i=index" class="upload-files">
                      <div class="">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
                      </div>
                      <img id="blah" *ngIf="!isPdf(image.Location)" [src]="image.Location"
                        (click)="getURL(image.Location)" />
                      <span class="preview" (click)="delete(i)">delete</span>
                    </div>
```

I want to add checkbox with every image of this array and checkbox should be selected one at a time.
Tried to add but all get selected together.
SHould I use formarray here?
P.S - I am new to angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Radio button with same name so when you select one, other will deselect.

```
<input type="radio" name="something">
```

Here is a working demo -
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-avqyzs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. But in your working demo too I can select multiple checkboxes. I want to select only one and when i click on other the first one should deselect.

Comment: Ok then use Radio button with same name. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-avqyzs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select only one item then you should use radio button instead of checkbox.

Give value to radio buttons and for getting value use **(change)** event.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Tried radio buttons too. By giving " type = radio " in the same manner as above. But still if i select one and then I click on the other radio button then both get selected. How can I select one and when i click on the other one the first one should deselect?

Comment: Here is the Demo You can use as a reference :
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcvmkc?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you posted, I guess you are using Reactive Form as well since you already know about FormArray so in my code below I just added the form element.

You need to change the checkbox to radio so that you will only select one option. in the code below, I'm assuming that the value you want in your radio button is the image location but you can just change it to the property that you want. You also need to assign a formControlName to your radio button to get the selected value.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div *ngFor="let image of result; let i=index" class="upload-files">
    <div class="">
      <input type="radio" formControlName="image" [value]="image.Location">
    </div>
    <img id="blah" [src]="image.Location"
      (click)="getURL(image.Location)" />
    <span class="preview" (click)="delete(i)">delete</span>
  </div>
</form>
```